# Backbone child view removal infinite loop

Tags: backbone.js, foreach, underscore.js, parent-child, backbone-views

I am trying to remove all child views in Backbone by modifying the Backbone.View.prototype like this:

```
_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype, {
childViews:[],
close: function(){
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    console.log(this.childViews.length);
    _.each(this.childViews,function(childview){
        childview.close();
    },this);
}
});
```

So when I create a child view, I `push` to childViews.  When I `close` I expect it to also call `close` on the childViews.  If it has nothing in childViews, then I expect the chain of `close` to stop.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Drc92/3/)

What ends up happening is some sort of infinite loop.  I can't figure out why it is behaving like this.  Is it a problem with `_.each`'s `[context]`?  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you've added `childViews: []` to the prototype. That means that every single view instance will share exactly the same `childViews` array. Once you have any child views anywhere, you will end up with `this.childViews` containing `this` and there's your infinite loop.

Instead, you should create `childViews` in the view's `initialize`:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.childViews = [ ];
    //...
}
```

You might have to update your `close` method to allow for an `undefined` `this.childViews` as well.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f2ykv/

---

As a rule of thumb, you almost never want any mutable properties (such as arrays or objects) attached to the prototype, you almost always want those properties assigned per-instance.